# Turn off forced change sudo passwd

Tags: sudo, passwd

I add line to sudoers:

```
user1 ALL= EXEC: PASSWD: /usr/bin/passwd user1
```

and when I use "sudo passwd user1" simple password is applied:

```
Password: 
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: it is too short
BAD PASSWORD: is too simple
Retype new password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

How can I turn off forced change password by root?

-rwsr-x--- root root /usr/bin/passwd.shadow

So user1 can run passwd only as root. But I need to allow user1 change passwd for user1 and user2. And user2 should change passwd only for user2. I use sudoers for this:

```
user1 ALL= EXEC: PASSWD: /usr/bin/passwd user1
user1 ALL= EXEC: PASSWD: /usr/bin/passwd user2
user2 ALL= EXEC: PASSWD: /usr/bin/passwd user2
```

Comment: can you edit the post with the result of `sudo -u user1 passwd user1` ? as I see it, the first password ask is by `sudo` to go from current user to `root` (thus the line user1 .. is not applied), then as you are changing password as `root`, old password is not asked, and you can enforce low quality password.

Comment: and on a side note, `user1` didn't need sudo to change password.

Comment: It is restricted run passwd from user1.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the command you're running with `sudo` is `/usr/bin/passwd`, not `/usr/bin/passwd.shadow`. It is not immediately obvious why `passwd.shadow` is mentioned at all: it is possible that `passwd.shadow` is an auxilliary command that is used by the main `passwd` command.

Even without `sudo`, each user can change their own - and *only* their own - password by using the `passwd` command with no parameters. When it is used in this way, any password quality checks configured in PAM cannot be bypassed by typing the new password a third time, like root (or someone running `passwd` as root via `sudo`) can do.

If you want to remove the password quality checks, in Linux they are usually controlled by PAM module `pam_cracklib.so`, `pam_passwdqc.so` or `pam_pwquality.so`, depending on Linux distribution used. There may be configuration files for these modules in `/etc/security/` directory, or you can comment out the modules altogether from the configuration files in `/etc/pam.d/` if you want to accept very simple passwords.

If the `passwd` command is working normally, you should only need `sudo` to allow user1 to change user2's password, like this:

```
user1 ALL= EXEC: PASSWD: /usr/bin/passwd user2
```

Allowing everyone to change everyone else's passwords is effectively the same as giving everyone unrestricted root access. That is usually a bad idea.

Comment: passwd = /usr/bin/passwd (it is link) = /usr/bin/passwd.shadow. So I have remove executable for other permision for passwd. Seems I should revert it (thanks for your comment). Also I find `enforce_for_root` option which help me with `sudo passwd` and short passwords.

Comment: Yes, `/usr/bin/passwd` is designed to have setuid root permissions, and will behave differently when run by a root user/sudo vs. someone non-root. When run by a non-root user, it will only allow that user to change his/her own password and won't allow bypassing the password quality checks. When run as root (either through sudo or as a real root user), it will allow more options.